# JQuery/AJAX form validation with nested testing...elegant solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I'm performing form validation using JQuery/AJAX. When an entry is missing or malformed, I want to send a message via alert() and return the user to the form with all fields as they were so the user can edit them and try submitting the form again. I also don't want the user to get a series of alert() boxes for each field that is malformed, but rather the first field that is discovered to be malformed should issue an alert() box; upon clicking the alert() box, the user may then return to editing the form. If there are 6 malformed fields, I don't want a series of 6 consecutive alert() boxes, but rather just the first one discovered by the routine to be errant and a return to the form (eventually the user will get them all right).

I have utilized a method that works, although it's not elegant and rather tedious to edit and error-prone...it's like a series of Russian dolls, where the first error prevents the successive routines from being run. When there are 5 fields or fields that require multiple kinds of integrity checking, the number of nested IF-ELSE statements increases exponentially, and for forms where I'm passing data via GET to a PHP file, like this:

```
$.get('admin_email_length_check.php', { new_email: $('#new_email').val(), max_email_length: max_email_length }, function(data) {
    if (data != 0) {
        alert(data);
    } else {
```

...it has to be closed out with:

```
    }
});
```

...not just a simple:

```
}
```

But here's a short routine for a 2 field validation. I set allow_submit to FALSE and prevent submission until all integrity checks are passed, at which point allow_submit becomes TRUE and I dynamically re-submit the form; this means that the integrity check (and its e.preventDefault();) will be bypassed entirely and the form will then be processed. Again, it works, but the kind of IF-ELSE structures I need to construct for forms with many fields that require many types of form validation requires extremely LONG structures with carefully edited closing braces (or braces + parentheses + ;, etc.) Is there a shorter or more elegant way to do this?:

```
var allow_submit = false;
$('#change_password_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (!allow_submit) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // First ensure that at least one of the fields has a value:
        if (($('#new_password').val() == '') && ($('#retype_password').val() == '')) {
            alert("Nothing specified in either of the 'Change Password' fields.\n\nAdd data and re-submit.\n");
        } else {
            // Ensure both fields are filled:
            if (($('#new_password').val() == '') || ($('#retype_password').val() == '')) {
                alert("When changing your password, both the 'New Password' and the 'Retype Password' fields must be filled.\n\nPlease supply new, matching passwords in both fields and re-submit.\n");
            } else {
                // Do the two fields match?
                if ($('#new_password').val() != $('#retype_password').val()) {
                    alert("New Password fields do not match.\n\nPlease edit password fields and re-submit.\n");
                 } else {
                    allow_submit = true;
                    $('#change_password_form').submit();
                 }
            }
        }   
    }
});
```

Comment: The trick is to store a binary error flag in a variable, and you only have to do un-nested if/else evaluation of each field. For each evaluation, update the error flag to `true`, and push then nature of the error into an array. After all the if/else statement, simply check if the error flag is still true or false. If false, fetch the first element in the error array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two suggestions:

1. Use early `return` statements to de-nest your code a bit.
2. Whenever you have too much conditional logic, try to use a data structure instead. [See this quote by Linus Torvalds](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163185/torvalds-quote-about-good-programmer).

Here is my attempt:

```
$('#change_password_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var data = collect_data();
    if (!data_is_valid(data)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // Submit.
    }
});

function collect_data() {
    return {
        passwords {
            new_: $('#new_password').val(),
            retyped: $('#retype_password').val()
        },
        ...
    };
}

function data_is_valid(data) {
    if (!password_is_valid(data.passwords)) {
        return false;
    }
    ...
    return true;
}

function password_is_valid(passwords) {
    for (var i = 0; i < password_validators.length; i++) {
        var validator = password_validators[i];
        if (!validator.fails(passwords)) {
            alert(validator.message);
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return true;
}

var password_validators = [
    {
        fails: function(passwords) {
            return passwords.new_ === '' && passwords.retyped === '';
        },
        message: 'No password provided'
    },
    {
        fails: function(passwords) {
            return passwords.new_ !== .passwordsretyped;
        },
        message: 'Passwords do not match'
    },
    ...
];
```